# python POST upload large file without loading it to memory

Tags: python, python-requests

i'm trying to POST upload large files with multipart/form-data encoded, but i want to use `requests` module only, not using `requests_toolbelt`.

is there anyway i can upload the file by chunking it to reduce memory usage?

here's my current code

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('url', files={'report.mp4': f})
    print(r.text)
```

the reason i don't want to use requests_toolbelt, is that when i request the POST the code finishes running, it doesn't give any error, it just finishes and the request text is empty

here's the code that i'm using that fails.

```
m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={'file': ('filename', open(file, 'rb'), 'video/mp4')}
)

r = requests.post(url, data=m,
                  headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```